# Extract a full-scale image from a SVS file

Tags: c, tiff, libtiff

I am trying to extract the first page of a SVS file using Libtiff.
The SVS file uses JPEG2000 compression for this image.

My plan is:

1. extracting raw tiles from the first page of the SVS, and
2. decoding it using OpenJPEG.

Below is what I tried to extract raw tiles from the SVS. I only got a 43KB output file from 152MB svs file (it failed to extract the raw tiles).

I hope someone could let me know how to extract tiles from a SVS file.

```
int main()
{
    const char* filename = "input.svs";
    TIFF* tiff_in = TIFFOpen(filename, "r");
    TIFF* tiff_out = TIFFOpen("output.raw", "w");
    if (tiff_in) {
        uint32 imageWidth, imageLength;
        uint32 tileWidth, tileLength;
        uint32 tileCount, tileByteCounts;
        uint32 samplePerPixel, bitsPerSample;
        uint32 orientation, planarConfig, photoMetric;
        uint32 xResolution, yResolution;
        uint32 x, y;
        ttile_t tile;
        // get fileds from the input file
        TIFFGetField(tiff_in, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &imageWidth);
        TIFFGetField(tiff_in, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &imageLength);
        TIFFGetField(tiff_in, TIFFTAG_TILEWIDTH, &tileWidth);
        TIFFGetField(tiff_in, TIFFTAG_TILELENGTH, &tileLength);
        TIFFGetField(tiff_in, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, &samplePerPixel);
        TIFFGetField(tiff_in, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, &bitsPerSample);
        TIFFGetField(tiff_in, TIFFTAG_TILEBYTECOUNTS, &tileByteCounts);
        TIFFGetField(tiff_in, TIFFTAG_ORIENTATION, &orientation);
        TIFFGetField(tiff_in, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, &planarConfig);
        TIFFGetField(tiff_in, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, &photoMetric);
        TIFFGetField(tiff_in, TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION, &xResolution);
        TIFFGetField(tiff_in, TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION, &yResolution);

        // set files to the output file
        TIFFSetField(tiff_out, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, imageWidth);
        TIFFSetField(tiff_out, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, imageLength);
        TIFFSetField(tiff_out, TIFFTAG_TILEWIDTH, tileWidth);
        TIFFSetField(tiff_out, TIFFTAG_TILELENGTH, tileLength);
        TIFFSetField(tiff_out, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, samplePerPixel);
        TIFFSetField(tiff_out, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, bitsPerSample);
        TIFFSetField(tiff_out, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, planarConfig);
        TIFFSetField(tiff_out, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, photoMetric);
        TIFFSetField(tiff_out, TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION, xResolution);
        TIFFSetField(tiff_out, TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION, yResolution);
        //TIFFSetField(tiff_out, TIFFTAG_ROWSPERSTRIP, 1);

        tdata_t buf = _TIFFmalloc(TIFFTileSize(tiff_in));
        for (int tile = 0; tile < TIFFNumberOfTiles(tiff_in); tile++)
        {
            TIFFReadRawTile(tiff_in, tile, buf, (tsize_t)-1);
            TIFFWriteRawTile(tiff_out, tile, buf, (tsize_t)sizeof(buf));
        }
        _TIFFfree(buf);
        TIFFClose(tiff_in);
        TIFFClose(tiff_out);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing tiles with 8 bytes each. `sizeof(buf)` is the size in bytes of the pointer `buf`. You want to use the number of bytes actually read, which is returned by `TIFFReadRawTile`:

```
tsize_t size = TIFFReadRawTile(tiff_in, tile, buf, (tsize_t)-1);
TIFFWriteRawTile(tiff_out, tile, buf, size);
```

Note that here you are copying the JPEG2000-compressed data to the output file. You'll have to decompress this data using OpenJPEG, then write data of the size of the uncompressed tile, which is `tileWidth * tileLength * samplePerPixel * bitsPerSample / 8` in the contiguous planar configuration, or `tileWidth * tileLength * bitsPerSample / 8` in the separate planar configuration.

---

When using `TIFFGetField` and `TIFFSetField`, you need to check the return values. A 0 is returned if an error occurred. You cannot depend on values that were not read properly.

Other errors and warnings are typically printed to `stderr`. If you are developing under Windows, these will typically not be shown. I recommend that you look into [`TIFFSetErrorHandler`](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/man/TIFFError.3tiff.html) and [`TIFFSetWarningHandler`](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/man/TIFFWarning.3tiff.html), setting suitable message display functions here will help you immensely during development.

Comment: Thanks for answering, @Cris Luengo. I could write a raw tiles using your suggestion. I think I should decompress when reading tile by tile not after extracting all. What do you think? Does it make the process faster? I am looking on (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154962/how-to-read-jp2-using-openjpeg-c-tile-by-tile) this as a reference but it seems not easy to use. Could you give me a simple workflow for decompressing jpeg2000 ?

Comment: @YJJ: I thought you'd want to save uncompressed tiles, from your description. Since all you're doing now is copy the compressed tiles over from one TIFF file to another, this step seems kind of pointless. I don't have any experience using OpenJPEG, I really don't know how to use it either. The question you found seems to contain all the code you need, though. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, @Cris Luengo. After extracting tiles by using "TIFFReadRawTile", the result file should be JPEG2000 formatted image file, right? When I opened the file, a width and height of the image was right, but the pixel values looked noisy. I thought it could be opened by an application that handles ".jp2" or ".j2k" format.

Comment: @YJJ: You are writing a TIFF file, with J2K-compressed tiles (because you use LibTIFF to write it!). I don't know what the ".jp2" or ".j2k" format is like, what you need to do to write that.

Comment: If you have enough memory, you can read the whole image into memory, then use another image writing library to save the image. But most of those libraries (and image formats) don't support images this large. This is the reason we use tiled TIFF: it's a very convenient format to store these large images!

Comment: I understand. Like you said, It is just a tiff file containing jp2 format tiles. So, if I want to get the whole image into memory, there is no library to support that? In the case, I have to write by myself. to memcpy all values in all tiles into an array with the size of the full-scale image is the right way? What I don't understand here is that, let's say the tile size is 250 and using Separate planar, should it have 3 tiles with 250 size for presenting one tile-sized colored area ? also what about Contiguous planar? the size will be 3 times bigger than 250 ? (sorry for the messy questions)

Comment: @YJJ: There might be some library/file format that supports very large images like these, I don't know. Most software I've tried craps out. Yes, you'd `memcpy` tiles line by line into a larger buffer. Separate planar configuration means that each tile contains values for one color only (you'll get all red tiles first, then all green tiles, then all blue tiles). Contiguous planar configuration means each tile has RGB data, with the three values for each pixel together in memory. The latter has tiles 3x as big as the former, and the former has 3x as many tiles.

Comment: @YJJ: Yes, that is what you should try to do. Make sure you have enough memory to hold that.

Comment: Now I am dealing with Contiguous planar. but the tile size is 256x256. shouldn't it be 256*3 x 256*3 to have [R,G,B] pixel values? Or actually the each tile represent only 256/3 x 256/3 sized RGB tile ? 256/3 is not even an integer value. sorry I am little confused now.

Comment: @YJJ: yes, the SVS file is always contiguous. Each tile has tileWidth * tileHeight * samplesPerPixel * bitsPerSample/8 bytes, but note that these are compressed, and so the raw tile should have fewer pixels.

Comment: >@Cris Luengo: Thanks for the info. I realized that each tile is just one-dimension array. Should I make the output buffer as a 2-dimension array having the full-scale width and height Or I can just memcpy all tiles into the output buffer as a 1-dimension array (lining up) ?

Comment: @YJJ: Each tile contains data for a 256x256 region of the larger image. You cannot just copy all pixels to the output array without taking geometry into account. Think about how the pixel data for the larger image is organized in memory. Each tile is composed of a set of lines, each line is 256 contiguous pixels, but the lines are not stored contiguously. You need to figure out the memory address for each of them. This is not complicated, but it is not as trivial as `memcpy` the full tile in one go.

Comment: I see. there are 10764 tiles in the svs. I can access for each tile with tileOffsets[tileNumber]. You said, each tile is composed of a set of lines. Then, How can I know a size of each line ? 8bit*256pixels? Or tileByteCounts/(256*numberOfColorChannel) ? I want to know a size of each line to memcpy a tile line by line.

Comment: Data is stored "R-G-B--R-G-B--R-G-B--" etc. So each image line has `imageWidth * samplesPerPixel` values (and you can assume each value is a byte with an SVS file). Each tile line has `tileWidth * samplesPerPixel` values. There are `tileHeight` lines in a tile. There are `ceil(imageWidth/tileWidth)`x`ceil(imageHeight/tileHeight)` tiles. I think from that you can compute which tile belongs where, and which line from each tile belongs where.

Comment: Each tile line: tileWidth * samplesPerPixel. I see. Thanks for letting me know. So, the output buffer has to be a 2-dimension array with (imageWidth * samplesPerPixel)  by (imageHeight).

Comment: Hi, @Cris Luengo. Sorry for asking you several times. How is YCbCr color space structured? is it the same as RGB? like "Y-Cb-Cr--Y-Cb-Cr--..." with "imageWidth * 3 * imageHeight" amount ? Now I am also decoding YCbCr space into raw values, but after decoding, the amount of raw values seemed different than raw values decoded from RGB.

Comment: @YJJ: That depends... it can be formatted like RGB, but it can also be compressed by reducing the number of Cb and Cr values. The reasoning is that we are less sensitive to changes there. For example JPEG does this, sometimes with half the chromacity values, sometimes with 1/4. I don’t know what the order is in that case, it must be specified by the standard. You should look for the JPEG standard to learn more about that.

Comment: Thanks. I only know how to change Ycbcr values to RGB values one by one. But if the number of Cb and Cr values are reduced, is there any way to convert them to RGB values (like R-G-B--R-G-B--...)?

Comment: Then the Cb channel is subsampled, you can retrieve the full-scale image back using e.g. linear interpolation, or just replicate each sample 2 or 4 times. Then you'd do the same with Cr.

Comment: Thanks, Cris. I could handle it by replicating Cb and Cr values 2 times because this time the format was 4:2:2. I could know the chroma subsampling format by looking the pixel value directly. could I get the format not by looking directly? for making this  can cope with both formats.

Comment: @YJJ: Is this a JPEG compressed TIFF file you are talking about? See [TIFF specification, supplement 2](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/specification/TIFFphotoshop.pdf). The tag [YCbCrSubSampling](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/ycbcrsubsampling.html) should specify this. But you're better off letting LibTIFF decode the JPEG stream for you. You can look at what the compression is, if it is something LibTIFF can handle, ask for the decompressed tile, if it is J2K, ask for the compressed data.

Comment: Yes, this was a JP2 compressed TIFF file. I decompressed a JP2 file and got the raw YCbCr data using OpenJpeg. I should look up OpenJPEG document. Thanks again :)

Comment: Consider [OpenJPEG's code](https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/blob/master/src/bin/jp2/opj_decompress.c#L1591) to convert chroma subsampled JP2 images to RGB. Works for me.