# Open or manipulate Jpeg2000 compressed Tiff

Tags: .net, image, image-processing

I'm building an app to process single page `tif(f)` files and batch them into pdf's using [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).  Running into issue with certain files where they will open or process but only as a black page.  Seems to be limited to the greyscale or color images.  I know they are not corrupt because they open in third party ISV application.  They however seem to be compressed using a pretty obscure algorithm.  So far i've tried -and failed- to open them with:

1. Every built in windows image viewer
2. [IfranViewer](https://www.irfanview.com/)
3. [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/)
4. [Faststone](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm)
5. PhotoShop

When I run the ImageMagick `Identify` command I get the following:

> identify: compression not supported

The only thing i've been able to find so far that will open them is [Brava!Desktop](https://www.opentext.com/products-and-solutions/products/enterprise-content-management/content-centric-applications/opentext-brava/opentext-brava-for-desktop).  This however is a commercial app and doesn't seem to take commands for automating this conversion process - which is what I need.

Does anyone know what format this is in or how I would go about about rendering it properly in .net.

### Edit

Additional EXIFTOOL info `exiftool.exe Black.tif -v 5` Thankyou too fmw42 for bringing that tool to my attention !:

```
| 0)  SubfileType = 2
| 1)  ImageWidth = 2534
| 2)  ImageHeight = 3323
| 3)  BitsPerSample = 8 8 8
| 4)  Compression = 34712
| 5)  PhotometricInterpretation = 2
| 6)  StripOffsets = 228
| 7)  Orientation = 1
| 8)  SamplesPerPixel = 3
| 9)  RowsPerStrip = 3323
| 10) StripByteCounts = 11742587
| 11) XResolution = 300 (300/1)
| 12) YResolution = 300 (300/1)
| 13) PlanarConfiguration = 1
| 14) ResolutionUnit = 2
| 15) PageNumber = 0 0
```

Comment: Some tif files are JPG compressed with an older JPG compression that many tools do not support. It could also be a custom compression. Using EXIFTOOL, I get `259 Compression                     : 34712` which does not seem to be listed at https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/compression.html. What tool created the TIFF file? Do you have the option to change the compression when creating it.

Comment: I note that Photoshop will not open it either.

Comment: @fmw42 The files are made by a ISV medical software record application called all-scripts so I have no control on that end.  I put in a case with them and they're telling me it's a `"standard"` tiff compression but they don't know what type.  The interesting thing is that this open-text brava desktop application will view them, like you said I'm assuming it's an older JPG compression.  Hoping someone has run into it before.

Comment: @fmw42 I've been poking around with EXIFTOOL and comparing to https://www.awaresystems.be page you provided I noticed the very last format has 34712 compression.  `COMPRESSION_JP2000 = 34712;`.  Does that point me in the right direction on how to decode ?

Comment: Even if it is JPG2000 compressed, I still do not know of any tool that will decompress the TIF or even open it. JPG2000 is a more advance lossless compressed format. But TIF is so open, that anyone can modify it and there is no real standard with all the possible customization. So it is likely that few tools at this time will open/decompress the TIFF. If it were a standard JPG2000 file, there are tools that will deal with it. See the OpenJPEG documatation which is one tool that creates and reads JP2000 format. That might help. https://www.openjpeg.org

Comment: @fmw42 Yeah the only thing I've found so far is https://www.opentext.com/products-and-solutions/products/enterprise-content-management/content-centric-applications/opentext-brava/opentext-brava-for-desktop

Comment: Check with the libtif developers. Imagemagick uses libtif. See if there is a new version that supports JP2000 compression.

Comment: I'm reading in the forums over there now and looking into http://kakadusoftware.com/downloads/ too it supposedly does JPEG2000

Comment: OK. But do they deal with TIFF files with JP2000 compression? I do not see anything about that. But I have not looked in depth

Comment: @cgohlke done I thought the one I put was just a blank face sheet but I wasnt able to open and verify to see

Comment: You can extract the compressed strips or tiles from the TIFF file, using LibTIFF, and then decompress them using Kakadu. JPEG2000 is standard across many industries, it is a very good compression scheme that doesn't create the same artifacts that the older JPEG does. Note that, contrary to what has been said in the comments above, JPEG2000 is a lossy compression scheme (though it has a lossless mode).

Comment: @CrisLuengo I’ve been trying google how to do that in C# but am having trouble finding anything.  Image manipulation is not something I work with allot.  Can you point me in the right direction to extract the strips or tiles ?

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna: I presume you can interface to LibTIFF from C#, but I have no experience with it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53698754/7328782) might get you started, there's C code there to read raw tiles from a TIFF file, and some information on decompression. If the TIFF file is in strips, code is similar but with [`TIFFReadRawStrip`](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/man/TIFFReadRawStrip.3tiff.html), and [`TIFFTAG_ROWSPERSTRIP`](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/man/TIFFGetField.3tiff.html), instead of the stuff with "tile" in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (using Python):

1. [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/), with [imagecodecs](https://pypi.org/project/imagecodecs/) installed, can read the image into a numpy array, which can then be further processed:

   ```
   from matplotlib import pyplot
   import tifffile
   im = tifffile.imread('black.tif')
   pyplot.imshow(im)
   pyplot.show()
   ```
2. Open the file in binary mode, seek to StripOffsets, read StripByteCounts bytes, and write the buffer to a .jp2 file, which can be opened with IrfanView etc:

   ```
   with open('black.tif', 'rb') as fh:
       fh.seek(228)
       im = fh.read(11742587)
   with open('black.jp2', 'wb') as fh:
       fh.write(im)
   ```

Comment: Will try this when I get back in front of my computer thanks

Comment: Hi thanks for this solution !  This has been a pain in the but to figure out.  Quick question python is not one of my primary languages.  Is it possible to save as jpeg or do I have to use another library ?